# Custom Shape Button in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, shapes

How can i make a custom shaped button as i drawn in image in Android?

I want to implement ui like below.[image]

Can any one help me ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: will be a hard stuff...You can draw Your own view in onDraw of a custom view or You have to use ImageButton and draw this by Yourself with a good drawing programm.

Answer (score 1):

Here are simple way to implement it just use layout, the works layout is FrameLayout

**[Graphical Layout]**
[image: Graphical Layout]

**[post.png]**

[image: post.png]

**[add_a_video.png]**

[image]

**[layout.xml]**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:src="@drawable/add_a_photo" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:src="@drawable/facebook" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:src="@drawable/facebook" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:src="@drawable/facebook" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:src="@drawable/facebook" />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton1" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/post" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/add_a_video" />
</FrameLayout>
```